# Joining based on Sum of amount

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Basically there are 2 files

File 1 sample

| Reference | Amount |
| --- | --- |
| AA1 | 1000 |

File 2 sample

| Reference | Match_No | Side | Amount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AA1 | 123 | Ledger | 1000 |
| BB1 | 123 | Statement | 500 |
| CC1 | 123 | Statement | 500 |

Now the requirement is using the reference from File 1 extract the Match_No from file 2 where side = 'Ledger'

The script I think for this should be:-
select file2.match_no
from file1 join file2 on file1.reference = file2.reference
where side = 'Ledger'

Now after extracting Match_No where side = Ledger, for the same Match_No extract all the references from file 2 where side ='Statement' and sum of file2.amounts (where side='Statement') = file2.amount(where side = Ledger)

Comment: Your explanation in words is not entirely clear, and the example is not sufficient to illustrate the potential issues. From what you posted, what is the desired output? The **exact** output - meaning which columns, and what rows (with what values in them). Then, suppose the last row (reference = CC1) had an Amount 0f 300, or of 600, instead of 500. What would be the desired result in THAT case, and according to what precise logic?

Answer (score 0):

This is how I understood what you are saying. See if it helps.

```
SQL> with
  2  -- Sample data; you have it already & don't type it
  3  file_1 (reference, amount) as
  4    (select 'aa1', 1000 from dual),
  5  file_2 (reference, match_no, side, amount) as
  6    (select 'aa1', 123, 'Ledger'   , 1000 from dual union all
  7     select 'bb1', 123, 'Statement',  500 from dual union all
  8     select 'cc1', 123, 'Statement',  500 from dual
  9    ),
 10  -- Useful code begins here.
 11  -- Query you posted (I added "B.AMOUNT" and used it in line #21)
 12  qyp as
 13    (select b.match_no, b.amount
 14     from file_1 a join file_2 b on a.reference = b.reference
 15     where b.side = 'Ledger'
 16    )
 17  -- The final query
 18  select b.reference
 19  from file_2 b join qyp q on q.match_no = b.match_no
 20  where b.side = 'Statement'
 21    and q.amount = (select sum(c.amount)
 22                    from file_2 c
 23                    where c.match_no = b.match_no
 24                      and c.side = 'Statement'
 25                   );

REF
---
cc1
bb1

SQL>
```